# Is my Snake Obese?

Tags: diet, snakes

I have a 6yrs old adult male corn snake who looks a little obese.

When he curls up in his hide you can see his skin quite clearly!

I feed him a big mouse every 12 days.

Comment: @SirArtherAndTheSnakesTable Wrinkled scales and skin showing means he's overweight. My advice is to try to feed him a little smaller mice at feeding times and try to encourage him to exercise.